# DNS resolution in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, dns

I use a VPN client to access my company's intranet. It used to work fine with older versions of Ubuntu. But on 12.04 it doesn't. It is able to connect but I do not see any packet exchange happening, hence not able to browse the Intranet.

During some troubleshooting I found out that in 12.04 DNS resolution has been changed, and my VPN client is not able to update the DNS server. After a little Googling I found a post which proposed adding the DNS nameserver IP addresses to `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` as follows.

```
prepend domain-name-servers <ip1>, <ip2>;   #this was the addition i made

request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
    domain-name, domain-name-servers, domain-search, host-name,
    netbios-name-servers, netbios-scope, interface-mtu,
    rfc3442-classless-static-routes, ntp-servers,
    dhcp6.domain-search, dhcp6.fqdn,
    dhcp6.name-servers, dhcp6.sntp-servers;
```

This resolves the issue and I can browse the intranet website. But this doesn't persist for a longer time. It appears the DNS gets changed after a while. Is there a way I can make DNS settings not to change, or every time it changes it should get those IP addresses also included ?

Comment: Please say which VPN client you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ubuntu 12.04, any changes made manually to `/etc/resolv.conf` will be overwritten later by a DNS information manager called `resolvconf`.

If you want to change the default settings, you could modify files `base`, `head`, or `tail` under `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d`.

- **base**: Used when no other data can be found
- **head**: Header of default resolv.conf. The server inside will the first
  ones to check.
- **tail**: entries appended at the end of resolv.conf. In
  some cases, upgrading from a previous Ubuntu release, will make tail
  a symlink to original

Ref:

[Auto DNS resolving in Ubuntu 12.04 desktop](http://oct.im/auto-dns-resolving-in-ubuntu-1204-desktop.html)

Answer (score 0):

Third-party VPN clients sometimes futz with /etc/resolv.conf and sometimes don't restore /etc/resolv.conf properly when they exit.

For background, see Launchpad bug #1000244 and, in particular, comment #121.

```
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/resolvconf/+bug/1000244/comments/121
```

To fix, try doing `sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf`.